# How to write and call an Oracle function in SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two Oracle tables with a similar structure:

[image]

I'd like to write a function in Oracle which sum all values for each ID and returns a pair (ID,Text) where Text='ALERT' if the sum is greater than 100, 'OK' otherwise:

[image]

Then, I'd like to execute a query for each table, for example something like that:

```
SELECT MY_FUN() FROM TABLE_1
SELECT MY_FUN() FROM TABLE_2
```

Is this a right approach? How could I write this function?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want a function when you can get that result from a fairly straightfoward query? (Also, please post formatted text, [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/266304)).

Comment: This is a strongly simplified example than that one I want

Comment: Your simplified example can be done with simple aggregation and a case expression - no new function needed. How can we guess what the right approach is for your real situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is considered bad practice to call a function in SQL which executes SQL. It creates all kinds of problems.

Here is one solution:

```
create or replace function my_fun
  ( p_sum in number) return varchar2 is
begin
    if p_sum > 100 then return 'ALERT';
    else return 'OK';
    end if;
end;
/
```

Run it like this:

```
select id, my_fun(sum(val)) as state
from your_table
group by id;
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a function for this, rather than just `select id, case when sum(value) > 100 then 'ALERT' else 'OK' end as state ...` that I'm missing? Or are you just humouring the OP's desire to involve a function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in sql like the following.  If you want to create a function to to this for different tables, you can wrap this in a function that takes the table name and run the query via dynamic SQL, but you are limited to the same columns.

```
-- begin test data
with test_data(id, value) as
  (select 1, 100 from dual union all
   select 1, 50 from dual union all
   select 2, 75 from dual union all
   select 3, 50 from dual union all
   select 3, 51 from dual)
-- end test data   
select id, sum(value),
       case when sum(value) > 100 then 'ALERT'
       else 'OK' end AS alert
from test_data
group by id;
```